# Configuring Inbound security rules of Azure Load Balancer

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-load-balancer

I have created a AKS and deployed a simple web server on it with following yaml.
Azure LoadBalancer gives a public IP address to it automatically and works fine.

Now I would like to limit the source IP address so I can access it from a specify IP address only.
I've tried adding a Azure Firewall to the virtual network of AKS (aks-vnet-XXXXXXX) with some network rule but doesn't work.

Creating a NAT rule in Firewall and redirects packets to the LoadBalancer works
 but I can still access the pod with the Public IP address of the LoadBalancer.

Any suggestions?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
(skipped something not important)
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.17.6
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve can be done with NSG (Network Security Group) applied to the subnet where your AKS cluster resides: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-security#network-security

More generic approach with a fine-grained control will require creation of [Ingress Controller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic), creation of an `Ingress` object for your service and applying `ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range` annotation to it.

Comment: There is a default "AllowAzureLoadBalancerInBound" rule but I cannot change it (Priority 65001). I have tried accept my ip address with priority 100 and reject all IP address with priority 200, and I cannot access it anymore.

Comment: you can't apply an NSG to a load balancer, you need to create and NSG and apply it to the subnet where your AKS resides https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-overview#securebydefault

Comment: Creating a new NSG and applying it to the aks-subnet works! Saved a lot of time and cost for Trial-and-erroring those complicated Azure Firewall / Frontdoor / application gateway / virtual network. Thanks a lot!